# excel vba compare one range with another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite massively out of my depth here having never used vba before (My main role is primarily sql based), i'd like to sit down and spend a few days actually learing how all this works but i don't have days right now, hence throwing myself on your mercy!

```
Sub updateduration()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I4").Value = "Y" Then
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H4").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Else
  If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J4").Value = 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H4").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
  Else
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J4").Value = 0 Then
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H4").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

As ugly as that probably is it works, Im now trying to adapt it so it adjusts all the cells in range H4:H34 one by one checking each if statement against the equivelant cell (i.e. range I4:I34 and range J4:34)

I've been looking at 'for each' to form an initial loop but am struggling to figure out how to specify which cells in the other ranges to look at in each iteration of the loop.

Any help or advice appreciated

L

Comment: Is the range "fixed" ? or is it being selected by the user ? or passed in by another process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE, L! You're off to a good start, and you're right that a FOR..NEXT loop is what you're looking for. The trick is to edit your Range with a variable, like this:

```
Sub updateduration()
Dim startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer
startRow = 4 'first row to compare/update
endRow = 34 'last row to compare/update

For myRow = startRow To endRow
  If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & myRow).Value = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & myRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
  Else
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & myRow).Value = 1 Then
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & myRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
      If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & myRow).Value = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & myRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next myRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellant stuff, you have provided the missing link in my understanding - 'Range("J" & myRow)'. I hadnt understood it was that simple to combine text & a variable within a range declaration, Id been trying to form variable that updated itself in each iteration but was getting befuddled in multiloop hell.

Many thanks for such a quick response, saved my bacon!